# ReactEditText.java , Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: react-native, null-pointer, android-textinputedittext

Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable android.graphics.drawable.Drawable$ConstantState.newDrawable(android.content.res.Resources)' on a null object reference

I am using React Native version 0.66.4, got the crashes in firebase Crashlytics for ReactEditText.java.
I have tried multiple solutions but nothing worked for me .